# Dynamically created button not working in IE non-compatibilty mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

so I have a large amount of divs and what I am doing is displaying a button when the user hovers over the div. When the user clicks on the button it will do something. The problem at the moment is that in IE when I click on the button the button just disapears and does nothing. It works in Chrome FF and even IE when it has Compatibility mode on. The code is as follows.

```
     function highlightUnmarked ( field ) {
    $( field ).addClass("hover-markedfields");

    var selectedText = $('<div>').append( $( field ).clone() ).html();

    if ( ( selectedText.search( 'triangle-isosceles' ) == -1 )
        && ( selectedText.search( 'triangle-isosceles-blue' ) == -1 )   ) {

        var markButtonsDiv = document.createElement( "div" );
        markButtonsDiv.id = "markButton";

        var initialLink = document.createElement('a');
        initialLink.setAttribute('href', '#');
        initialLink.setAttribute('id', 'initial');
        initialLink.onclick = function() { initial() };

        var initialImg = document.createElement('img');
        initialImg.setAttribute('src', '<?php echo Yii::app()->params['DIRECTORY_NAME'] ?>/images/initial.png');

        initialLink.appendChild( initialImg );

        markButtonsDiv.appendChild( initialLink );

        $(field ).prepend( markButtonsDiv );

    } 

}
```

The function called just does not execute. I have put an alert as the first part of the function and its just not called. The worst thing is no error is thrown so I cannot seem to figure out what is wrong.

Below is the code for the function that is called. It just throws a popup.

```
    function initial () {

        $.blockUI({
            message: $('#popup2'),
            centerY: true,
            css: {
                top:  ($(window).height() - 200) /2 + 'px',
                left: ($(window).width() ) /2 + 'px',
                width: '400px',
                height: '',
                margin:'50px 10px',
                padding: '10px 20px 5px 5px',
                color: 'black'
            }
        });
}
```

Thanks for any help.

EDIT: Sorry guys, simple mistake was preventing it from working in FF.

Comment: Can you include your event code please?

Comment: Sure, one min and ill get it up now.

Answer (score 0):

Is Your Code not working in IE itself?If your Code even not working in chrome then below is the solution...

Jquery UI components are compatible with GoogleChrome Version 18+.It May be your problem.

Comment: Hi Baskar, the code works in Google Chrome and works in IE with compatibility mode on. It does not work in FF or IE with non-compatibility view.

Comment: Oh Ok chaney.I dont have idea regarding your issue.